# NixOs: Can’t setup development with electron: Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: node.js, electron, nixos

I need to create a project involving electron and some libraries (easymidi), but I can't find how to do:

- If I install electron from Nix directly, for instance using `nix-shell -p electron_17`, I can start a basic hello world project, but then I can't import other node libraries (if I install them with `yarn`, I get an error about unknown symbols, I guess because `yarn` and the nix `electron` runs different nodejs version
- If I do everything using yarn or npm, electron can't even start a basic hello world folder:

```
$ nix-shell -p yarn
$ git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
$ cd electron-quick-start/
$ yarn install
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.15
  $ electron .
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /tmp/c/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/electron ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:280:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn /tmp/c/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/electron',
  path: '/tmp/c/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/electron',
  spawnargs: [ '.' ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Any idea what I did wrong? How can I setup electron with some random libraries like easymidi?

**EDIT**

Here is the log file (tried the same with npm, same error):

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/nix/store/06680csx89n416lvsy2yljmw6rvibj8y-nodejs-14.18.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/nix/store/06680csx89n416lvsy2yljmw6rvibj8y-nodejs-14.18.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~prestart: electron-quick-start@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: electron-quick-start@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: PATH: /nix/store/06680csx89n416lvsy2yljmw6rvibj8y-nodejs-14.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/tmp/d/electron-quick-start/no
de_modules/.bin:/nix/store/yx24h6ywbkg7rm5x7lrm8mx8ypcf4ywi-bash-interactive-5.1-p8/bin:/nix/store/fj3ywsx22xvjd4mly4323ikjcavyv91v-patchelf-0.13/bin:/nix/store/s5hkav7whndbfz0szshpb46h4idqdq9a-gcc-wrapper-10.3
.0/bin:/nix/store/a2w3l1m75908yd05a0h40vnrzvxfd0gd-gcc-10.3.0/bin:/nix/store/mfz26azl9561jgd5n73nkszzp6qhsaal-glibc-2.33-50-bin/bin:/nix/store/xyn0240zrpprnspg3n0fi8c8aw5bq0mr-coreutils-8.32/bin:/nix/store/5d5j
1z9bg01wqxahihy2x5n22ykc32w8-binutils-wrapper-2.35.1/bin:/nix/store/a4mmjm3bblxwp8h53bcfx3dly80ib0ba-binutils-2.35.1/bin:/nix/store/06680csx89n416lvsy2yljmw6rvibj8y-nodejs-14.18.0/bin:/nix/store/xyn0240zrpprnsp
g3n0fi8c8aw5bq0mr-coreutils-8.32/bin:/nix/store/1nq62klcc9n2jv2ixaf77makkzdcghrh-findutils-4.8.0/bin:/nix/store/xwkxkx4bk005q35hsdhqbkbdv7g28cz5-diffutils-3.8/bin:/nix/store/dy4ylp9439la4lq35ah2mj80fi87pk4w-gnu
sed-4.8/bin:/nix/store/xxgddhdi57bbgd1yxza44plq6krjmiz1-gnugrep-3.6/bin:/nix/store/31pkw5yi08fj4l0glzvpf1cp4ywkxh86-gawk-5.1.0/bin:/nix/store/nwg8in201f7y6vdm787v3j84jjrn0ayw-gnutar-1.34/bin:/nix/store/ygzg6wzh
gxf51ianb4zjvrzq4ilx9jd7-gzip-1.10/bin:/nix/store/gakfgapj20lv13vkcz6c38j8i9vz4ypi-bzip2-1.0.6.0.2-bin/bin:/nix/store/xgp0bgw4rpnbc3vr2qdsdbixp3zy4v1l-gnumake-4.3/bin:/nix/store/wadmyilr414n7bimxysbny876i2vlm5r
-bash-5.1-p8/bin:/nix/store/347zp4r9a7gm5gk0gwijqw294nnyypcs-patch-2.7.6/bin:/nix/store/f2x98vk07px8916b9xid7jq6ky86sfmi-xz-5.2.5-bin/bin
9 verbose lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: CWD: /tmp/d/electron-quick-start
10 silly lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'electron .' ]
11 silly lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle electron-quick-start@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/nix/store/06680csx89n416lvsy2yljmw6rvibj8y-nodejs-14.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/nix/store/06680csx89n416lvsy2yljmw6rvibj8y-nodejs-14.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid electron-quick-start@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /tmp/d/electron-quick-start
16 verbose Linux 5.10.75
17 verbose argv "/nix/store/06680csx89n416lvsy2yljmw6rvibj8y-nodejs-14.18.0/bin/node" "/nix/store/06680csx89n416lvsy2yljmw6rvibj8y-nodejs-14.18.0/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.18.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**EDIT**

I also tried npm2nix-like tools, but they also failed.